# Grabbing screen resolution and displaying results based on the size

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to show results from a database based on screen resolution size. I posted a question last week about how to get the width and was able to come up with this jquery with the help of a few ideas here, but was unable to complete the second aspect, which is to display results based on the size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize = 1600) {
            //**This is where I need to define the $maxresults value, but how?**
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
</script>
```

Now, this is the second part:

```
<?php
    // get the function
    include_once ('function.php');
    $maxresults = 21;
    if ($_GET['page']) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    } 
    else {
        $page = 0; 
    }
    $currentpage = $page;
    $page = $page*$maxresults;
    $numpages = QuickQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM books WHERE visible=1");
    $numpages = mysql_result($numpages, 0);
    $numpages = $numpages/$maxresults-1;
    //Show <maxresults> pages at a time
    $result = GetBooksByRangeID($page, $maxresults);
    DisplayResults($result); 
?>
```

The max amount of results to show is set to 21, but I want to use the jquery above to define the amount based on a user's screen resolution; I will have various sizes. In other words, I need the if statement to say "show this many results based on the size found." So how do I write that if statement?

***LAST REVISION= Partially WORKING, (sets all results to max 6 despite resolution size) ***

```
<?php
// get the function
include_once ('function.php');
if(($_GET['w']) && ($_GET['h'])) {
    $w = $_GET['w'];
    $h = $_GET['h'];
}
if ($w == 1920) {
    $maxresults = 24;  
}
else if ($w == 1600) {
    $maxresults = 24;  
}
else if ($w == 1440){ 
    $maxresults = 12;
}
else if ($w == 1366) { 
    $maxresults = 10;
}
else if ($w == 1024) {
    $maxresults = 8;
}
else  $maxresults = 6;
```

.....

Comment: you could get rusults using JSON, after testing windows properties ... good ressource >[HERE](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/)<

Comment: I'm already able to get the size- I tested with an alert- I just do not know how to write the if statement to say show this many results based on the size found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ajax, this is what needs to be done

```
<html><body>
<div id="content"></div>
....
<script>
    $(function(){
      $.ajax({
         url: 'file.php',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {h: screen.height, w: screen.width}
      }).done(function ( data ) {
         document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

That file.php would then run your database query and return a nicely formatted set of results (i.e. html table) based on the h and w parameters sent via ajax which tell you the height and width of the screen. To do this just set the $page variable depending on the size of the `$_GET['w']` and `$_GET['h']` variables. See below:

```
<?php
// get the function
include_once ('function.php');
$maxresults = 21;

$page = ( $_GET['page'] ? $_GET['page'] : 0 );

if(($_GET['w']) && ($_GET['h'])) {
  $w = $_GET['w'];
  $h = $_GET['h'];
  //$maxresults = // calculate this depending on w and h
  // i.e. if h > 1600 $maxresults = 20, else = 10
  $currentpage = $page;
  $page = $page * $maxresults;
  $numpages = QuickQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM books WHERE visible=1");
  $numpages = mysql_result($numpages, 0);
  $numpages = $numpages/$maxresults-1;
  $result = GetBooksByRangeID($page, $maxresults);//Show <maxresults> pages at a time  
  //DisplayResults($result); 
  echo $results; // in a nice format (i.e. table) to be inserted into div via ajax
?>
```

You can calculate $maxresults as follows:

```
if($w > 640) && ($h > 480) $maxresults = 5;
if($w > 800) && ($h > 600) $maxresults = 7;
if($w > 1024) && ($h > 768) $maxresults = 12;
....
if($w > 2560) && ($h > 1600) $maxresults = 21;
```

Or you can group these statements by width (as I think thats less important than height, meaning less scrolling down for the user):

```
if ($w <= 1024) {
  if ($h >= 768) $maxresults = 12;  // 1024x(768 or higher)
  else if ($h >= 600) $maxresults = 8; // 1024x(600~768)
  else  $maxresults = 6; // 1024x(599 or below)
}
else if ($w <= 1280) {
  if ($h >= 1024) $maxresults = 14;  // 1280x(1024 or higher)
  else if ($h >= 960) $maxresults = 12; // 1280x(960~1024)
  else if ($h >= 800) $maxresults = 10; // 1280x(800~960)
  else if ($h >= 768) $maxresults = 8; // 1280x(768~800)
  else  $maxresults = 6; // 1280x(768 or below)
}
//and so on
```

### see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution#Computer_monitors

Revision

You code for populating maxresults is very poorly written, thats why it does not work. Try this:

```
<?php
include_once ('function.php');
$maxresults = -1;
if(($_GET['w']) && ($_GET['h'])) {
  $w = $_GET['w'];
  $h = $_GET['h'];

  if ($w == 1920) {
    $maxresults = 24;  
  } else if ($w == 1600) {
    $maxresults = 24;  
  } else if ($w == 1440){ 
    $maxresults = 12;
  } else if ($w == 1366) { 
    $maxresults = 10;
  } else if ($w == 1024) {
    $maxresults = 8;
  } else 
    $maxresults = 6;
}
echo $maxresults;
```

This will either output -1 if w and h are not being sent or it will return 24 or 12 and so on depending on your screen width. Learn to do some basic debugging on your code. It is difficult for me to debug your code without having all of it to hand.

Comment: The browser will download resources for all screen sizes which is never going to be a good thing.

Comment: depends on what the content is, Im sure the OP said something along the lines of a $maxresults variable, which is just a number, not a load of text/images.

Comment: @hussman Those max results represent returned results from a database query which could return images .etc, if the data is small it's not much of a problem but not ideal. The problem is we don't know the size of the data returned here.

Comment: @JJM You must use Ajax, this is not possible on a single page request because JavaScript runs after PHP has finished processing. Alternatively if they visit a page before this you can store their resolution in a cookie and attempt to grab that before going down the ajax route.

Comment: @Geeorge nope, those max results represent a variable like $maxresults = 21; The problem isnt that we dont know the size, the issue is that it is just a variable, an integer to be exact.

Comment: @JJM, indeed if you want to use PHP to display the number of results, then Ajax is the way to go to set the screen resolution.

Comment: @hussman the max results represent 21 images 320x450 and text

Comment: Fair enough, answer modified to use Ajax to return data depending on JS screen width detection.

Comment: @husman thanks! Can you elaborate on this line: just set the $page variable depending on the size of the $_GET['w'] and $_GET['h'] variables...not sure what you mean

Comment: See the PHP code I added to my answer, especially where it says '$maxresults ='

Comment: for   $maxresults = // calculate this depending on w and h
  // i.e. if h > 1600 $maxresults = 20, else = 10
are you meaning I need to do this manually or keep code as is? Sorry, I am new to this

Comment: Been at this for hours- just do not know how to work the $maxresults without a better example

Comment: Why dont you just use an if/else. if (w==???? && h==????) $maxresult=??; else if (w==???? && h==????) $maxresult=??; Something like that. It will be long winded but the simplest solution.

Comment: @husman thanks where do I place the new if statements you have shown and do I remove the original $maxresults=21; altogether?

Comment: The new if statements would be placed just below where it says: "$w = $_GET['w'];
  $h = $_GET['h'];" There are comments there so it shouldnt be too difficult to figure out. Also I would recommend you leave the $maxresults=21; as a failsafe just incase someone is using a non standard screen size. They will get the default of 21.

Comment: I can tell my if statements are not correct as only some of them work. Thanks for your patience! I'm new to this

Comment: if statements check equality with a == (double equals), you have put a single =, meaning that you are assigning w the value instead of comparing it.

Comment: @husman- it actually isn't working. I get only 6 results despite switching to == how can I test if the height and width are actually being identified? Any other ideas?

Comment: well instead of echoing the results in the php code, why dont you echo $_POST['w']?

Comment: I can work with this-- thanks for all of your help- you went above and beyond!

Answer (score 1):

Just load the ajax by passing the answer via de `$_GET['windowsize']` and use the results that are returned via the "data" variable(this can be HTML that is inserted into the DOM but also an json string or what ever you want it to be.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize = 1600) {
            $.ajax('/path/to/page?windowsize='+encodeURIComponent(windowsize)).done(function(data){
                        // the stuff to do when the php is loaded, for example, document.getElementById('x').innerHTML=data;
                        });
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

</script>
```

in the php script you could post:

```
<?php
$windowsize = (int)$_GET['windowsize'];
if($windowsize >= 1200 && $windowsize < 1400)
    {
    echo "maxsize:200;minsize:300;";
    }
if($windowsize >= 1400 && $windowsize < 1600)
    {
    echo "maxsize:300;minsize:400;";
    }
```

then in the javascript you could use:

```
..........done(function(data) {
    $results = data.split(';');
    for(c=0;c<$results.length;c++)
        {
        $tmp = $results[c].split(':');
        if($tmp[0] == 'minsize')
            {
            minsize=parseInt($tmp[1]);
            }
        if($tmp[0] == 'maxsize')
            {
            maxsize=parseInt($tmp[1]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I know little to nothing about ajax- can you explain to me what needs to be on the page your defining there? When the php is loaded, I just want to show maxresults

Comment: I've added some extra code.
You can put in the php output anything you want. The javascript ajax variable(called data in my example) is simply a string containing what the php script outputs.
If you do view source on the php script you see the value the string will hold.

Comment: thanks. I am going to be trying out all of the ideas presented here today-

Comment: I was able to get your ideas working as well- but I did adjust to this: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize > 768) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "functions/movie2.php",
          data:{windowsize:encodeURIComponent(windowsize)},
      });
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
</script>   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution would be to submit the screen-resolution per Ajax to the php script. Then use the resolution to determine  the amount and return the movies for example as json.

Something like this:

**EDIT

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {'use strict';

   var screenResolution, request;

   //set screen resolution here
   screenResolution = 1024;

   request = $.ajax({
     url : "url_to_php_script",
     type : "POST",
     dataType : "json",
     contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
     data : {
        "screenResolution" : screenResolution               
     }
  });
   request.fail(function() {
      alert("fail");
   });

   request.done(function(movies) {
      console.log(movies);
   });
});
```

php:

```
$screenResolution = $_POST['screenResolution'];

//DO your normal Stuff

$jsonResult= json_encode($result);

return $jsonResult;
```

Comment: If it isn't too much trouble, can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure just give me one moment